# Passive voice with direct and indirect object pronouns

Tags: gramática, voz-pasiva

Let's consider the following sentence

> Se lo di *meaning* I gave it to him

`Se` is the indirect object pronoun and `lo` is the direct object pronoun. Now if the sentence above is to be put in the **passive voice** form we would have to introduce `se`, but here is the case `se` is there already for a different purpose. A typical passive sentence would be

> Se escribió el libro en español *meaning* The book was written in Spanish

So how I do use the passive voice with a direct and indirect object pronoun, in this case

> It was given to him

Would it be *Se lo dio* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passive construction to which you're referring is usually called *pasiva refleja* ("reflexive passive [voice]"), because of the use of the reflexive pronoun *se*.

The passive form that would correspond to *«Se lo di»* would be

> *Se le dio.*

What's happening here? The passive voice shifts the arguments of the verb. The subject is deleted and the direct object is promoted to subject. The **indirect** object, if there is one, stays the same.

In this case, the pronoun *se* in *«Se lo di»* is the indirect object. It refers to the third person singular, and it should be *le*, but there's a grammar rule that says that when both *le* (indirect object) and *lo* (direct object) appear in a proposition, then *le* turns into *se*.<sup>note</sup>

In order to turn this into a passive with *se*, you do the following:

1. Delete the subject. This is easy in your sentence, since the subject is already implicit (*yo*).
2. Promote the direct object to subject. In *«Se lo di»* the subject is *lo*, a third person singular masculine pronoun. When you make it the subject, you delete it (as is usual in Spanish): *lo* → *ello* → ∅, but you must turn the verb into its third person singular form: *di* → *dio*.
3. You keep the indirect object, but since there is no more direct object the rule above doesn't hold, so *se* reverts to its "normal" form: *se* → *le*.
4. You add *se* to make this a *pasiva refleja*.

[image: Se le dio]

You might be wondering what happened to the first person singular implied in the original sentence (*«**Yo** se lo di»*). In this kind of passive construction that information is lost; you cannot re-introduce it. This is different from what happens with the other type of passive, the so-called periphrastic passive voice, which is more like the English passive voice.

**Note:** The rule actually says that the indirect object pronouns *le* and *les* both change to *se* when a direct object pronoun (one of *la, lo, las, los*) is present in the proposition. So this whole answer also holds for *«Se la di»*, *«Se las di»* and *Se los di*; and when making the change into passive, *se* could also turn into *les* (there's no way to know where the recipient of the action is singular or plural, because *se* is ambiguous).